# What is best practice when implementing an Admin Panel for a MEAN Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, admin, panel, mean

I am a complete beginner to all aspects of the MEAN stack. I have a minimal implementation of an application that pulls data from a MongoDB and displays the data on an angular front end using a RESTful API. The front end was generated using yeoman. I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

I have done some research into admin panels that I can integrate with node and best practices. I have found ready made panels such as this one: https://github.com/jedireza/drywall

My Questions are as follows:

How do I go about directing a user to either my application or the admin panel at login? Do I use express for this?

If I wanted to implement drywall (link posted above), how could I go about integrating it with my current application? i.e. Do I have to download drywall and then write my code within the files that come with it, or can I somehow integrate it with my currently written application?

Comment: I've been wanting to add one of these for awhile and this one looks awesome. I'll definitely be playing with Drywall and post something here if I come up with an answer for you

Comment: Hey man, what exactly you are expecting for in return of this question. Best practice is something we could debate on all the time mate. I haven't used drywall but I am checking it out now. I have been working on MEAN stack from a few months, at this point of time I just directly use routing module on the front end and for node.js part, I directly handle the requests made to the server.

Comment: As a beginner I'm simply looking for a way in which I could route users/admins to my app/admin panel, so any method you use would be useful. I want to see how it can be done. So how exactly do you handle the requests made to the server directly? Using express? And could you elaborate on using the routing module on the front end?

Comment: @GandalftheWhite sorry, answer above

Comment: ? Do you need more explanation bro.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite, yes please, that would be great. So how exactly do you handle the requests made to the server directly? Using express? And could you elaborate on using the routing module on the front end? I used the Yeoman generator to generate my front end. I was able to hook it up to the mongoDB using restangular. However I am confused as to how I can somehow work an admin panel into this. I have a Yeoman Angular front end and a node server backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Angularjs for the front end and Node.js with Express at the backend.

I am going to paste one demo of my routing.

Angular JS Routing Example - Using Routing Module

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/txn_history', {
            templateUrl: 'views/add_user.html',
            controller:'mainCtrl'
        })
```

Express JS

Attached the directory for usage

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/test'));
```

Using Routes Module for Node & adding a JS file that has function to add user

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var route_add_user = require('./routes/add_user');
```

Calling the function with the route here; .adduser is function name within that js file

```
 app.get('/adduser', route_add_user.adduser);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this and a lot of other research has helped!

Comment: I am glad mate. Best of luck for future.